# How to map a table valued function to a query type in EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table valued function on SQL Server

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FStatusDepo] 
(   
    @ProvozID int, @ZonaID int NULL, @minutesWarning int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT 
      q.[DepoID]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.Vjezd IS NOT NULL AND datediff(mi, v.Vjezd, GETDATE())>@minutesWarning THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS VjezduPoLhute
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.Vjezd IS NOT NULL AND datediff(mi, v.Vjezd, GETDATE())<=@minutesWarning THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS VjezduVLhute
  FROM 
  ...
```

I have a new project with ASP.NET Core 2.1 and EF Core 2.1.

[I have read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/modeling/query-types) that I can define a new `Query` type within DbContext:

```
public class  StatusDepo
{
    public int DepoID { get; set; }
    public int VjezduPoLhute { get; set; }
    public int VjezduVLhute { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
            .Query<StatusDepo>().ToView("FStatusDepo");
```

When I look at the example:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/samples/QueryTypes/Program.cs

I see there, that I should probably also add this line to the DbContext:

```
    public DbQuery<StatusDepo> StatusDepos { get; set; }
```

Then I am able to execute:

```
   using (DixieContext db = new DixieContext())
    {
        var listStatusDepo = 
              db.StatusDepos.FromSql("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusDepo] (1, 1, 20)").ToList();
    }
```

This works OK but the line:

```
    modelBuilder.Query<StatusDepo>().ToView("FStatusDepo")
```

has no purpose at all, is there any other construct for parametrized views or should I just delete the line and use FromSql only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any other construct for parametrized views or should I just delete the line and use FromSql only?

Yes. You should remove `modelBuilder.Query<StatusDepo>().ToView("FStatusDepo")` It does nothing here because you're not mapping your class `StatusDepo` to a SQL VIew but you're using a SQL Function that returns a table.

EF Core `ToView()` method is for mapping a class to a SQL View (and configure mapping property to columns if needed) so you'll not need to write your SQL because EF will know how to generate it for you.

In your case your code below is sufficient:

```
using (DixieContext db = new DixieContext())
{
    var listStatusDepo = db.StatusDepos.FromSql("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusDepo] (1, 1, 20)").ToList();
}
```

Comment: This requires creating a `DbSet` for the given type, but what if my TVF returns its own type that doesn't match an actual table? I shouldn't add a `DbSet` for it since EF Core would then attempt to perform regular queries against it if I don't use `FromSql`, right?

Comment: The ToView() is so that an EF knows that it does not map to a table. This is the opposite of ToTable()